# foreach doesn't stop the loop on break

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to post 3 arrays using `foreach` and for some reason the `break` at the end isn't working and it outputs the whole list (40+) on to the page.

```
$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements

shuffle($line);

$i = 0;

foreach ($line as $number) {
    {  
    if($i==3){ break; } else {
    $rtime = mt_rand(1, 7);
    echo $number; }

   $i++;
}

}


}
fclose($file);
```

This is kind of how it looks: take.ms/cLgIh, instead it should only show 3 of these usernames.

Comment: You arent increasing $i.

Comment: fixed the code and updated the question. the outcome is the same.

Comment: while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)   Have you traced this to verify that break; is not honored?

Comment: @Paparazzi not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloade first sample CSV from here:-http://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-csv.php

And this code works for me:-

```
<?php

$file = fopen('SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
      //$line is an array of the csv elements

    shuffle($line);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($line as $number) {  
        if($i==3){ 
            exit;
        } else {
            $rtime = mt_rand(1, 7);
            echo $number.'<br/>';
            echo $i.'<br/>'; // you can remove this line    
        }

       $i++;
    }


}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Output on each page refresh:-

http://prntscr.com/cln2ju

http://prntscr.com/cln2nf

*Note:- if still not work then check your CSV file. May be it is corrupted.*

*Conclusion:- And after all discussion it comes to an end that your CSV file is corrupted. But yes code improvement is needed too*

Comment: What a great idea to output $i value! Now we can all see that $i isn't increasing for some reason. http://take.ms/Wav5D

Comment: @Ricardo  that means either you csv have some problem or while loop is not working correct.

Comment: Thanks, like suggested by you and Sunny - my csv was corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
//I have opened my contact.csv :P
$file = fopen('contact.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
shuffle($line);

foreach ($line as $number) {
    {  
    if($i==3){ exit(); } else {
    $rtime = mt_rand(1, 7);
    echo "<br/> i = ".$i.$number.", "; }
}
 $i++;
}

}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Really strange, this is what I see: http://take.ms/YCYMV (again, all of them instead of 3) I totally copied your code. Maybe it has something to do with my xampp?

Comment: try it now, and try to use another csv file

Comment: Thanks, like suggested by you and Anant - my csv was corrupted.

Comment: :) happy Coding... ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment `$i` otherwise it's value will always be **0**

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($line as $number) {
    $rtime = mt_rand(1, 7);
    echo "$number";

   if($i==3) break;
   $i++;
}
```

Also you need to check if your while statement is closing

```
$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    //$line is an array of the csv elements

    shuffle($line);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($line as $number) {
        $rtime = mt_rand(1, 7);
        echo $number;

        if($i==3) break;
       $i++;
    }
} //check for this
```

As I can see in your code example it is missing the closing brace

Also, remove the double quotes from your $number, it's not necessary.

```
echo $number
```

Comment: @Ricardo Please provide some details when reporting a problem. Do you mean "it didn't run", "it threw an exception", "nothing happened", "the same thing happened", etc, etc. A simple "It doesn't work" is not helpful.

Comment: @Basic, what I meant is that it kept writing the whole list on the page.

Comment: I've tried your code in http://phpfiddle.org/ with a random array and the break happened when `$i == 3`, you need to check your array then because maybe something is breaking before the increment and the `if` condition

Comment: @DannyG 1) Done 2) Checked, it's there 3) It's not just `$number`, I have more personal code there that looks like: `<p class='details-desc'> Viewed your photo. &nbsp  $rtime s </p>`

Comment: @Anant I want to output 3 random arrays from names.csv

Comment: @anant doesn't help.

Comment: Alright, but you might want to recheck your csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake is that the break are in the `if($i==3)` and you declared `$i =0`, but never increment this. So `$i` never arrive at 3.